# If $u$ is harmonic and vanishes on the boundary, then $u\equiv 0$.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let's assume $u$ is harmonic on $D=\{x^2+y^2\leq1\}$. If $u=0$ on  $\partial D$ then $u\equiv 0$ on $D$.

$\textbf{Proof}$:
Let's use Green's theorem and set $P=-u\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ and $Q=u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$.

Then

$$1. \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}
=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+ 
u\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+ 
\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2+ 
u\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2
=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+
\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2. 
$$

By Green's theorem,
$$
0=\int_{\partial D} -u\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dx+u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dy=\int \int_{D}
\left(
\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+ 
\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2\right)dxdy. 
$$

Because $u\in C^2$, we get

$$
\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2 + 
\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2=0.
$$

So $u\equiv c$ on $D$ but on $\partial D$ we have $u=0$. So $u\equiv 0$.

What have we done on the first move for $1$.?

Comment: You can also use the strong max/min principle of Harmonic Functions, which states that non-constant Harmonic Functions attain their max/min only on the boundary. Since the value on the boundary is identically 0, we see it's max and min are 0, so it must be constant, e.g. $u \equiv 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second line of your proof, it should be:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}
&=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+ 
u\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+ 
\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2+ 
u \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}  \\
&=  \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2 
+ \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2 
+ u 
\underbrace{\left( \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
+  \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}\right)}_{0}  \\
&=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+
\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2 
\end{align*}
since $u$ is harmonic on $D$, i.e., $u$ must satisfy Laplace's equation.

Answer (score 1):

We have used the product rule; e.g.

$$
\partial_x Q = \partial (u \partial_x u) = (\partial_x u)^2 + u \partial_x^2 u.
$$

(Your notation seems a bit off at that point.)

Comment: Is the sentence true only on a circle?

Comment: In fact, I now recall that using probabilistic methods, one can show uniqueness on *arbitrary* open and bounded sets. @newhere